# Dynamically update menu contents with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, menu

I have a drop-down menu that I would like to dynamically update using jQuery. Is this possible, or will I need something like PHP to pull in the data from the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with a mix of `AJAX` and `jQuery`

**HTML:**

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
   <option value="1">one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
   <option value="3">three</option>
   <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "resource.php",
  success: function(d){
    $('#foo').append('<option value="' + d.value + '">' + d.description + '</option>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay, so if I stored the info to update as JSON for example, and then pulled this through with AJAX?

Comment: Correct, note that if the data that your going to get from the server is minimal you could store that in the HTML as an object literal on the load of the page - saving an `AJAX` request to the server...